# WebRTC alert when video feed is disconnected

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I am using `WebRTC` `getUserMedia` to grab a webcam feed like this...

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({

    video: {
        facingMode: "user",
    }

}).then(function (stream) {

    var video = document.getElementById('cam-stream');
    video.srcObject = stream;

}).catch( function (error) {

    console.log("Camera Stream Error : " + error.name + " - " + error.message);

});
```

I would like to display an alert if this feed is disconnected, so for example, if somebody unplugged a webcam or the webcam itself crashed.

I have looked at `ondevicechange` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/ondevicechange#Example but it is not obvious how to detect the current feed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Listen for the `ended` event on the video track like this where you get the stream:

```
stream.getVideoTracks()[0].onended = () => {
  console.log('someone unplugged the webcam');
};
```

Comment: Thank you, perfect solution!